# Have to map a list of lists to another list that has same length and write to excel in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

example:

```
list1 =['Name','Age','Gender']
list2 =[['John','Paul','Meline'],['28','32','26'],['Male','Male','Female']]
```

My output excel should be:

```
 Name     Age    Gender
 John     28     Male
 Paul     32     Male
 Melnie   26     Female
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(index=list1,data=list2).T
```

output of `out`:

```
    Name    Age     Gender
0   John    28      Male
1   Paul    32      Male
2   Meline  26      Female
```

If you want to save in excel use `to_excel()` method:

```
out.to_excel('filename.xlsx',index=False)
```